# Javascript animate back on time

Tags: javascript

Hey I have javascript animate slide that is suppose to animate when the browser refreshes. The Slide, slides out right to 0px and then after 500 is suppose to slide back in -280 the issue that I am having is that I can not get it to slide back in. There is an error in my code. Here is the code:

```
$("#slideout").animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"}, function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#slideout").animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500})
    }, 500);
});
```

The function does not work, can anybody post the code to fix it?

Comment: This is JQuery, not Javascript, please change the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've mistaken the parameters of [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  The method signature is either this:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Or this:

```
.animate( properties, options )
```

So if you're specifying options, then you should pass the complete function as the "done" option, like this:

```
$("selector").animate({right: 0}, { queue: false, done: function() {
    // next animation
} });
```

Note also, that you may want to animate `left` instead of `right` -- note that `right: 0` is equivalent to `left: $(window).width() - $("#slideout").width()`.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dU5uL/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like:

```
$("#slideout").animate({right:'+=200'},500,function(){}).delay(500).animate({right:'-=200'},{duration:500});
```

Or even more accurate I guess would be probably this:

```
$("#slideout").animate({right:'200px'},
                       "slow",
                       function(){
                         $("#slideout").animate({right:'0'},500);
                       })
```

The second one is probably more what you're looking for.